# using Gridview control inside a usercontrol

Tags: windows-store-apps

I am trying create UserControl with below requirements.

Usercontrol contains a gridview and in side gridview, I need to add a button element. So, the idea is :- if  usercontrol is used in any other page by providing a collection to ItemSource then list of buttons should be generated and Button content value should be one of the property value of type present in Itemsource collection.

I am pretty newbie to windows store app programming. I am trying to expose the gridview ItemSources property by creating dependency property so that ObservableCollection of any type can be mapped and trying expose a dependency property to bind to button content property. but not able to achieve the same. I would really appreciate if you could point to a sample application doing the same.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a small sample (i hope that's what you wanna do)...

**EDIT:** I finally edited my answer to provide the property which takes the property path. IF ANYONE HAS ANOTHER SOLUTION FOR THIS QUESTION, PLEASE LET ME KNOW!

Add a dependency property for the binding path:

First we create a dummy model which provides the title for our buttons:

```
public class SampleModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the usercontrol. The important thing here is the ItemsSource-Binding (ElementName = UserControl). Otherwise you'll bind to the UserControlItemsSource in the Parent-DataContext.

**EDIT:** The button has changed since my last answer!

```
<UserControl
x:Class="StackOverflow.ListUserControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:StackOverflow"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400"
x:Name="SampleUserControl">

<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding UserControlItemsSource, ElementName=SampleUserControl}" Background="DeepSkyBlue" SelectionMode="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Loaded="FrameworkElement_OnLoaded"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

... and the usercontrol's code-behind including the UsercontrolItemsSource:

**EDIT:** i added the dependency property **BindingPropertyPath** and the **FrameworkElement_OnLoaded** method since my last answer.

```
public sealed partial class ListUserControl : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<SampleModel> UserControlItemsSource
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<SampleModel>)GetValue(UserControlItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UserControlItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for UserControlItemsSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UserControlItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("UserControlItemsSource", typeof(ObservableCollection<SampleModel>), typeof(ListUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    public string BindingPropertyPath
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(BindingPropertyPathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BindingPropertyPathProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BindingPropertyPath.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindingPropertyPathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BindingPropertyPath", typeof(string), typeof(ListUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));


    public ListUserControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FrameworkElement_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        Binding contentBinding = new Binding();
        contentBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(this.BindingPropertyPath);
        button.SetBinding(Button.ContentProperty, contentBinding);
    }
}
```

Now we add the usercontrol to our main page (ListPageHost):

**EDIT:** Set the new dependency property **BindingPropertyPath** to the name of the property of the ItemsSource that you wanna use for the button.

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Add Item to ItemsSource" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></Button>
    <local:ListUserControl Grid.Row="1" UserControlItemsSource="{Binding SampleCollection}" BindingPropertyPath="Title"/>
</Grid>
```

In the mainpage's code-behind, we declare our mainpage-viewmodel (ListPageHostViewModel):

```
public class ListPageHostViewModel
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<SampleModel> _sampleCollection = new ObservableCollection<SampleModel>();

    public ObservableCollection<SampleModel> SampleCollection
    {
        get { return _sampleCollection; }
    }
}
```

... and the MainPage's (ListPageHost) code behind:

```
public sealed partial class ListPageHost : Page
{
    public ListPageHost()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ListPageHostViewModel();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
    /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = this.DataContext as ListPageHostViewModel;
        if (vm != null)
        {
            vm.SampleCollection.Add(new SampleModel() { Title = string.Format("new item {0}", DateTime.Now.Ticks)});
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that's what you're looking for. If you have any questions - let me know.
Regards, Alex

Comment: Hi Alex.. Thanks for your reply. the sample is very close to what I am looking for but need little more help.

Comment: Hi Alex.. Thanks for your reply. the sample is very close to what I am looking for but need little more help. In the above sample, you have used Title property in the SampleModel type in both UserControl's button content and in Main Page, SampleCollection but I want to create a dependency property for Title so that client of my usercontrol can map to the dependency property. I don't want the UserControl and MainPage to know about Title Property. I just want to make usercontrol loosely coupled. Is this achievable?? Pls let me know. and thank you very much for your help. Really a great help.

Comment: I will look at your question soon ... I'm out of office at the moment.

Comment: So you want to decide which property should be used for the button-text through a dependency property?

Comment: I updated my answer! Please let me know, if that's what you're looking for... Cheers, Alex